# Select2 & Ajax - Load values with select2 + ajax + multiple option

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I am trying to display some info at my select2 component, but it's not working 100%.

After some hours of searching, I did it:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {!! Form::label('lblRequisitos', 'Selecione os Requisitos') !!}
            {!! Form::select('requisitos[]', $requisitosVaga, null, ['id'=>'requisito', 'class'=>'form-control js-states', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('#requisito').select2(
        {
            placeholder: "Escolha a habilidade...",
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax:
            {
                url: '{{route('pesquisa-habilidade')}}',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params)
                {
                    return {q: $.trim(params.term)};
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element).find("option").each(function () {
                    data.push({id: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
                });
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

With it, the initial load is ok. But when I try to search the next value (when I try to edit), it cleans all options.

Comment: You should show what happens in `route('pesquisa-habilidade')` on controller side

Comment: @phaberest hello. At server side, it's all working 100%. I was just losing the "selected" itens. I just add  "$(this).prop('selected', true);" to option pre-loaded, and now it's ok. Thnks for care.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but i fix it.

Only add the follow line:

```
//.... At select2 function ...

initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var data = [];
            $(element).find("option").each(function () {
                data.push({id: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});

                // ADD this line to put the option selected
                $(this).prop('selected', true); 
            });
            callback(data);
        }
// ....
```

Now, it's working 100%.

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: what are you getting in the browser console ?

Comment: Hello @HasanAl-Natour. I dont had error msg. Just the options were clean when i put a new item on select2. Now it's ok. But i dont think that my solution is "acceptable", like a good pratice.

Comment: your issue is not clear to me but the line you added is selecting all options one at a time , so it not a good practice.

Comment: @HasanAl-Natour, when i call the initSelection, i have only the options that i have pre-selected (by the variable $requisitosVaga). On this select, i have a ajax becouse it search on 20k registers. And only load the pre-selected options to display, all the others are loaded by ajax.